# IOS 14 Admob ads implementation App Tracking Transparency

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob, att, apptrackingtransparency

I'm using Unity and Google Mobile Ads 8.7.0 to implement ads in my game. I've read Google Prepare for IOS here https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14. But confused where and how to implement the required source codes.
The file states that we should place -void requestIDFA in our XCODE project. Few videos on YouTube has placed the code in their AppDelagate.h script.

But Admobs SDK 8.7.0 dosent include an AppDelagate.h file. Where should I place the -void (requestIDFA) script from Google. Will anywhere suffice or must there be a specific place you implement it.

Comment: you need to add these in your Xcode project as described.

Comment: @PathakAyush I've done everything the admob file has previously described including SKADNetworks and updated Info Plist. I'm referring to this piece of code here : #import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
...
- (void)requestIDFA {
  [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
    // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
    // [self loadAd];
  }];
}  Do i place it any random Xcode script? or a certain script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably the one who asked me on my YouTube video, and I answered you.
However the simplest solution is to use the Unity package [iOS 14 Advertising Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.ads.ios-support.html), you find it in the package manager.

Comment: Yep, that was me haha. I've already uploaded my app through test flight before I asked that question. However, I've gone ahead and implemented the Unity adsupport for iOS 14 previously suggested. Thanks alot btw.